# Error when trying to pull live values from firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pull values from a live firestore database but am getting few errors with the code. I have used streambuilder to pull the data as it will need to be updated whenever there is a change in the database.

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final String userId;

  ProfileWidget(this.userId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream:Firestore.instance.collection('users')
            .document(userId)
            .snapshots(),
        builder:(context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
              return Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['sold'].toString())}
              else
                {return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}

class User {
  final int name;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : name = map['name'];

  User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

Following are the two errors i get:

> 1. 'error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentSnapshot'. (undefined_getter at [flutter_appprofilescreenfinal] lib\main.dart:37)
> 2. info: The value of the local variable 'user' isn't used. (unused_local_variable at [flutter_appprofilescreenfinal] lib\main.dart:34)

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, assuming your users each have `documents` property, you should access it like this

```dart
snapshot.data['documents'][0]['sold'].toString()
```

The second error is pretty simple. You defined user but never used it inside the StreamBuilder's builder function.